# Accepting JSON in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a JSON being send to a controller function of ASP.NET, the JSON looks something like this:

```
[{"Key":"Test23.txt","Size":6,"LastModified":"Thu, 01 Nov 2012 19:35:43 GMT"},
{"Key":"Test25.txt","Size":6,"LastModified":"Wed, 31 Oct 2012 21:02:51 GMT"},
{"Key":"Test28.txt","Size":6,"LastModified":"Thu, 01 Nov 2012 19:35:42 GMT"}]
```

How would I accept it in an MVC controller method and how do I parse it?

Thank you.

Comment: You may use [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for parsing.

Comment: Do you control the process of generating this JSON and making server request?

Comment: I have some control, I am developing the front-end which uses ExtJs, which in turn generates the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mvc will automatically bind this to a viewModel if it matches.

```
public ActionResult SaveFiles(List<FileViewModel> filesViewModel){

}
```

where your FileViewModel would be something like this

```
public class FileViewModel
{
  public string Key {get;set}
  public int Size {get;set}
  public DateTime LastModified {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default model binder can do all of this for you. There's no need to use any third party libraries. When passing collections into actions, they do need to be indexable. So you have to use an `array` or `List`.

```
// First, define your input model.
public class MyModel
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public int Size { get; set; }
  public string LastModified { get; set; }
}

// NExt, use that model in your action.
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel[] things)
{
}
```

And everything should wire up for you.

Comment: Nope, I use empty MVC4 project and there is no "default model binder".

Comment: Yes, there is... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Item
{
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public int Size {get;set;}
  public DateTime LastModified {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult MyAction(List<Item> items)
{

}
```